# Not able to access Mule payload element

Tags: variables, mule, record

I have an intermittent issue with Mule's batch:job

I am processing a bunch of records resulting from a query against Salesforce. Payload here is a hashMap that represents one resulting record from the query. This is my relevant code -

```
<batch:process-records>
    <batch:step name="sfdc2edge_event_create_step_process">
        <logger message="SFId: #[payload.Id]. Processing a record" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <logger message="Full Payload: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="log payload"/>
        <batch:set-record-variable variableName="sfId" value="#[payload.Id]" doc:name="Set Record Variable - sfId" />
```

This is the log output -

```
2015-12-31 09:01:43,818 INFO  SF2Edge_Event_Create - SFId: null. Processing a record [org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor]
2015-12-31 09:01:43,818 INFO  SF2Edge_Event_Create - Full Payload: {type=Event, Type=Client Transition Meeting - Internal, Id=00U3000000QF2uREAT, ActivityDate=2015-12-31, Account={type=Account, Id=null, EDGE_Customer_Number__c=219213}} [org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor]
2015-12-31 09:01:43,818 INFO  Record variable with key "sfId", not found on message using "#[payload.Id]". Since the value was marked optional, nothing was set on the record for this variable [com.mulesoft.module.batch.processor.AddRecordVariableTransformer]
```

As you can see the full payload (line 2 in log) has the element named "Id", but the first log entry can't get it, as well as the set-record-variable command.

Any idea why that element is not able to be accessed?

Comment: The problem is the payload content type, in your code, the payload is a simple String, so, `#[payload.Id]` won't work. You have to transform it according to your needs before any processing to a known content type like json, or java objects (map, list, object)

Comment: Davo, I failed to mention that this is an intermittent issue (edited the question). It works most of the time. Also, the payload is not a simple String. It is the result of a query against Salesforce, a hashMap. Most of the time, it works fine.

Comment: Do you expect Id=00U3000000QF2uREAT to be printed ?

Comment: Can you give this a try  ? #[message.payload.Id]

Comment: Naveen, Where were you when I needed you? :) Before you answered, I had painfully figured out that "message.payload.Id" always works. For some reason, "payload.Id" just stops working at times. MuleSoft Support was absolutely of no help. If you post this as an answer, you get the answer points !